# Notification.Builder.setSound has no effect

Tags: android, push-notification

I'm trying to play a sound when receiving a push notification. The gist of the code looks like this:

```
Resources r = getResources();
int resourceId = r.getIdentifier(soundName, "raw", context.getPackageName());
Uri soundUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + context.getPackageName() + "/" + resourceId);
mBuilder.setSound(soundUri);
```

However, only the default notification sound is played when the notification is received.

If I play the sound with `MediaPlayer`, it plays just fine. So I must assume that the URI is correct.

```
MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
mMediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
mMediaPlayer.start();
```

However, I would prefer to solve this through the notification instance itself instead of playing the sound manually.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somewhere else in the code, we were using `mBuilder.setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL)`, which implies `DEFAULT_SOUND`. The documentation for which notes:

> Use the default notification sound. **This will ignore any given sound.**